# Existence of Analytic Continuation of Second-Order Linear, Homogeneous Differential Equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, riemann-surfaces

I am self-studying the book *Riemann Surfaces* by Simon Donaldson. He leaves the proof of the proposition below as an exercise. It is clear to me that one can find local power series solutions at each point along $\gamma$; however, I am not sure how to construct local solutions such that they agree on their common domain of definition. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

### Proposition

Suppose $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma:[0, 1] \to \Omega$ is a path in $\Omega$. Furthermore, suppose $P$ and $Q$ are holomorphic functions defined on a neighborhood $U$ of $\gamma(0)$ with analytic continuations along $\gamma$. If $u$ is a solution to
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1.1}
        u'' + P u' + Q u = 0
    \end{equation}
on $U$, then $u$ has an analytic continuation along $\gamma$, through solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading up more on the theory of differential equations in the complex domain using [these notes](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Emilicic/Eprints/de.pdf), I was able to construct the following proof, which I'm pretty sure is correct.

## Proof

Denote $z_t \equiv \gamma(t)$. By the uniform continuity of $\gamma$, the fact that $P, Q$ have analytic continuations along $\gamma$ by assumption, and the fact that analytic continuations are independent of the specific choice of chain of discs, there exists a chains of discs $D_j := D(z_{t_j}, r_j)$ along $\gamma$ in $\Omega$, where $0 = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_J = 1$, $0 \leq j \leq J$, and $\gamma([t_j, t_{j + 1}]) \subseteq D_j \cap D_{j + 1}$ for $0 \leq j \leq J - 1$, and $P_j, Q_j \in H(D_j)$ such that $P_j = P_{j + 1}$ and $Q_j = Q_{j + 1}$ on $D_j \cap D_{j + 1}$ and $P_0 = P$ and $Q_0 = Q$ on a neighborhood $U_0$ of $z_0$.

Define $u_0$ as follows. Without loss of generality, since we can always increase the fineness of our chain of discs, suppose that $D(z_0, r_0)$ is a subset of $U$ and $U_0$, so $P_0 = P$ and $Q_0 = Q$ on $D(z_0, r_0)$. Since $D(z_0, r_0)$ is simply connected and $P_0 = P$ and $Q_0 = Q$ are holomorphic on $D(z_0, r_0)$, it follows by a theorem from differential equations that there exists a unique holomorphic function $u_0$ on $D(z_0, r_0)$ such that $u_0$ is a solution to the differential equation and satisfies the initial conditions $u_0(z_0) = u(z_0)$ and $u_0'(z_0) = u'(z_0)$. Furthermore, by applying the same theorem to $U$, it follows by uniqueness that the restriction of $u$ to $D(z_0, r_0)$ coincides with $u_0$ on $D(z_0, r_0)$.

Now, construct $u_j(z)$ inductively for $1 \leq j \leq J$ as follows. Suppose we have determined $u_{j - 1}(z)$ on $D(z_{j - 1}, r_{j - 1})$. Let $X_j = D(z_{j - 1}, r_{j - 1}) \cup D(z_j, r_j)$, and define the holomorphic functions $P_{j - 1, j}$ and $Q_{j - 1, j}$ on $X_j$, where $P_{j - 1, j}(z) = P_{j - 1}(z)$ and $Q_{j - 1, j}(z) = Q_{j - 1}(z)$ for $z \in D(z_{j - 1}, r_{j - 1})$ and $P_{j - 1, j}(z) = P_j(z)$ and $Q_{j - 1, j}(z) = Q_j(z)$ for $z \in D(z_j, r_j)$. Since $X_j$ is simply connected and $P_{j - 1, j}$ and $Q_{j - 1, j}$ are holomorphic on $D(z_0, r_0)$, there exists a unique holomorphic function $B_j$ on $X_j$ such that $B_j$ is a solution to the differential equation and satisfies the initial conditions $B_j(z_{j - 1}) = u_{j - 1}(z_{j - 1})$ and $B_j'(z_{j - 1}) = u_{j - 1}'(z_{j - 1})$, so we can define $u_j$ as the restriction of $B_j$ to $D(z_j, r_j)$. Furthermore, by applying the same theorem to $D(z_{j - 1}, r_{j - 1})$, it follows by uniqueness that the restriction of $B_j$ to $D(z_{j - 1}, r_{j - 1})$ coincides with $u_{j - 1}$ on $D(z_{j - 1}, r_{j - 1})$. By induction, it follows that there exists $u_j$ for $0 \leq j \leq J$ such that $u_j = u_{j +1}$ on $D_j \cap D_{j + 1}$ and $u_0 = u$ on a neighborhood of $z_0$, so we have constructed an analytic continuation of $u$ along $\gamma$.